# Inherit BroadcastReceiver from a parent Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have three activities: BaseActivity, ActivityA, ActivityB where ActivityA and B extend the BaseActivity. In both ActivityA and B, I have a BroadcastReceiver which handles some intents. There are some identical intents in both ActivityA and B that are currently handled by the same code. Since this violates the DRY principle, I want to handle the common intents in ActivityA and B in the parent class (BaseActivity). Is it possible to do so ?

Here are the code. The intent LOGIN_SUCCESS are the same in both ActivityA and B. While the ACCOUNT_UPDATE and JOURNAL_UPDATE intents are specific to the classes.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends RoboActivity implements Handler.Callback {

}


public class ActivityA extends BaseActivity {

    private final BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.INTENTS.ACCOUNT_UPDATE)) {
            updateGUI();
        }

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.INTENTS.LOGIN_SUCCESS)) {
            updateGUI();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Register which actions to listen to
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Constants.INTENTS.ACCOUNT_UPDATE);
        intentFilter.addAction(Constants.INTENTS.LOGIN_SUCCESS);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
    }
}

public class ActivityB extends BaseActivity {

    private final BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(Constants.INTENTS.JOURNAL_UPDATE)){
            updateGUI();
        }

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.INTENTS.LOGIN_SUCCESS)) {
            updateGUI();
        }
        }
    };

     @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Register which actions to listen to
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Constants.INTENTS.JOURNAL_UPDATE);
        intentFilter.addAction(Constants.INTENTS.LOGIN_SUCCESS);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the Security Section at the following link. I think this what you are looking for.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#security-and-best-practices

Comment: I don''t see why this is related to my problem. Could you elaborate it ?

Comment: @v4r-if two broadcast receivers are receiving the same broadcast then using priority you can keep check on which receiver handles it first.

Comment: The Security section discusses cross-app security. In my case, the messages are sent and received in the same application but different activities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if I am correctly understanding your question, it is possible to do what you are asking.

I know this is an old question at this point but since no one else has provided any code examples yet, I wanted to offer one possible solution.  I will not claim that this example is “best practice” because am not sure it is, but this is currently implemented in a large project I help work on so I know it works, and it seems to satisfy your requirement of “in-app messages.”  To keep the example concise, the code won’t run if you just try to copy and paste it into a project, but hopefully it illustrates the idea I’m trying to convey clearly enough that it makes sense.

The Base activity contains your Broadcast Receivers and a method they all call when receiving their individual messages.  If you override the ExampleBase.onBroadcastReceived() method in the classes that extend ExampleBase, they can each take care of their own specific tasks when the Account Update or Journal Update messages are received and the Login Success message or any other shared messages can be handled in the Base activity’s method.

Helper Classes:

```
public class BroadcastUtility {
    public static LocalBroadcastManager Manager(Context context) {
        return LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
    }

    public static void Register(Application context, BroadcastReceiver receiver, String intentName) {
        Manager(context).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(intentName));
    }

    public static void Unregister(Application context, BroadcastReceiver receiver) {
        Manager(context).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
}

public class Constants {
    // Your constants
    public class INTENTS {
        public static final String ACCOUNT_UPDATE = "ACCOUNT_UPDATE";
        public static final String JOURNAL_UPDATE = "JOURNAL_UPDATE";
        public static final String LOGIN_SUCCESS = "LOGIN_SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

Base Class:

```
public class ExampleBase extends FragmentActivity {
    private BroadcastReceiver mLoginSuccess = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // On receipt of the "Login Success" broadcast, call the ExampleBase.onBroadcastReceived(Intent) method
            onBroadcastReceived(intent);
        }
    };

    private BroadcastReceiver mAccountUpdate = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // On receipt of the "Account Update" broadcast, call the ExampleBase.onBroadcastReceived(Intent) method
            onBroadcastReceived(intent);
        }
    };

    private BroadcastReceiver mJournalUpdate = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // On receipt of the "Journal Update" broadcast, call the ExampleBase.onBroadcastReceived(Intent) method
            onBroadcastReceived(intent);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        // Register the Broadcast Receivers on create
        BroadcastUtility.Register(getApplication(), mAccountUpdate, Constants.INTENTS.ACCOUNT_UPDATE);
        BroadcastUtility.Register(getApplication(), mJournalUpdate, Constants.INTENTS.JOURNAL_UPDATE);
        BroadcastUtility.Register(getApplication(), mLoginSuccess, Constants.INTENTS.LOGIN_SUCCESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Unregister the Broadcast Receivers on destroy
        BroadcastUtility.Unregister(getApplication(), mAccountUpdate);
        BroadcastUtility.Unregister(getApplication(), mJournalUpdate);
        BroadcastUtility.Unregister(getApplication(), mLoginSuccess);
    }

    protected void onBroadcastReceived(Intent intent) {
        // Actions common to all activities extending this one can be done here in ExampleBase
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.INTENTS.LOGIN_SUCCESS)) {
            // Do ExampleBase stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Classes Extending Base:

```
public class ExampleA extends ExampleBase {
    @Override
    protected void onBroadcastReceived(Intent intent) {
        super.onBroadcastReceived(intent);
        // Actions specific to ExampleA can be done here
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.INTENTS.ACCOUNT_UPDATE)) {
            // Do ExampleA stuff
        }

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.INTENTS.JOURNAL_UPDATE)) {
            // Do ExampleA stuff
        }
    }
}

public class ExampleB extends ExampleBase {
    @Override
    protected void onBroadcastReceived(Intent intent) {
        super.onBroadcastReceived(intent);
        // Actions specific to ExampleA can be done here
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.INTENTS.ACCOUNT_UPDATE)) {
            // Do ExampleB stuff
        }

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.INTENTS.JOURNAL_UPDATE)) {
            // Do ExampleB stuff
        }
    }
}
```